# Need help in put war file into Tomcat using ant installer

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I have a `war` file and a Tomcat server. I'd like to put the `war` file into the Tomcat server using *AntInstaller* and I want the server subsequently restarted.

Is it possible?  Can anybody help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create user in tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tomcat-users>
       <role rolename="dbadmin"/>
       <role rolename="manager"/>
       <user username="BruceP" password="bwperry" roles="dbadmin,manager"/>
      <user username="JillH" password="jhayward" roles="manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Create the **build.properties** file

```
appserver.home=c:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.19  
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib  
deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps  
tomcat.manager.url=http://www.localhost.com:8080/manager   
tomcat.manager.username=username
tomcat.manager.password=secret
```

Create the **build.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="fax" basedir="." default="usage">
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
    <property name="javadoc.dir" value="doc"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="name" value="fax"/>

   <path id="master-classpath">
       <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
           <include name="*.jar"/>
       </fileset>
       <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
  </path>

  <target name="javadoc">
  <javadoc packagenames="faxapp.*" sourcepath="${src.dir}" 
  destdir="doc" version="true" windowtitle="Fax Application">
    <doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>= Fax Application 
      =</h1>]]></doctitle>
    <bottom><![CDATA[Copyright © 2011. All 
      Rights Reserved.]]></bottom>
    <group title="util packages" packages="faxapp.util.*"/>
    <group title="web packages" packages="faxapp.web.*"/>
    <group title="data packages" 
      packages="faxapp.entity.*:faxapp.dao.*"/>
  </javadoc>
</target>

<target name="usage">
    <echo message=""/>
    <echo message="${name} build file"/>
    <echo message="-----------------------------------"/>
    <echo message=""/>
    <echo message="Available targets are:"/>
    <echo message=""/>
    <echo message="deploy    --> Deploy application 
      as directory"/>
    <echo message="deploywar --> Deploy application 
      as a WAR file"/>
    <echo message=""/>
</target>

<target name="build" description="Compile main 
  source tree java files">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" 
      target="1.5" debug="true"
      deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="build" 
  description="Deploy application">
    <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" 
      preservelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="deploywar" depends="build" 
  description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
    <war destfile="${name}.war"
         webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </war>
    <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="*.war"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>


<target name="clean" description="Clean output directories">
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>

<!-- ============================================================ -->
<!-- Tomcat tasks -->
<!-- ============================================================ -->

<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
    <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="install" 
    classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="reload" 
    classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="list" 
    classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="start" 
    classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="stop" 
     classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
    <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>
```

**Ant tasks**

InstallTask --Installs a web application. Class Name: org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask
ReloadTask  -- Reload a web application. Class Name: org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask
ListTask  -- Lists all web applications. Class Name: org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask
StartTask -- Starts a web application. Class Name: org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask
StopTask  -- Stops a web application. Class Name: org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask